# It is possible to select a pie slice in the same way as it's possible to select a button?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

We're all familiar with the "button" on a webpage. You click a button and it triggers something.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something similar with slices of a pie, where each pie slice represents a button, and pressing the button would be the same thing as pressing an `@Html.ActionLink()`.

I could imagine doing an image map over a flat image, and I can go that route if I have no other options, but it would be more visually appealing if the pie slices can actually be pressed in the same way that a button can.

Is such a thing possible on an MVC webpage?

[image: Slices of pie]

Comment: You may use an svg image. Easy and fully customizable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/ImageMapster/default.aspx?demos.html) a perfect plugin for similar approaches.
here is its [repository](https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster)

ImageMapster is a jQuery plugin that lets you activate HTML image maps without using Flash. It works just about everywhere that Javascript does, including modern browsers, Internet Explorer 6, and mobile devices like iPads, iPhones and Androids

Comment: fixed. typo mistake.

Comment: I found the demo. This definitely fits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want you could combine an [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) with a separate image for each state of the "pie". You are showing a default state. You would need to create an image for each depressed state (one for each slice of the pie). The each image would show the whole pie with one or no item depressed.

Then, the best look would probably be to put them into a single image and use [CSS sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) to switch the image position (which will control which image is in the viewport) based on which image map section is clicked.